# Finder window resizes by itself

Tags: macos, finder

Every time I restart the computer or just Finder app the Macintosh HD folder will be resized to the default size without remember my configuration. Why? Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Finder remembers the bounds even for the root folder for me, but does `/.DS_Store` exist or get modified? Have you tried deleting it or deleting other support files?

Comment: @LauriRanta There isn't a .DS_Store in the folder. I think it has never been created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by copying a .DS_Store from another folder to Macintosh HD.
I don't know why but Finder wasn't going to create it by itself.